# Paint/plaster texture question

Tags: paint, plaster, texture, acrylic

My walls and ceiling are skip trowl lath and plaster and (many layers) painted, I’m doing some cutting and patching and using DAP Patching Plaster.  It goes on great but after I sand and paint it the texture looks too smooth compared to the old plaster/paint, how can I get it to look the same?  It looks like it’s a paint texture issue, I’m painting with small rollers and acrylic paint.

Lower center is desired texture, left and upper left around the square hole is too smooth

[image: too smooth patch]

Answer (score -1):

There are a ton of ways to texture wall surfaces (too many to list here), all require some expertise acquired through trial and error and a perfect match is nearly impossible.

Originally, when a craftsman plastered your wall, he likely used a wet float technique that allows the sandy aggregate in the plaster to rise to the surface. That is not a process you can easily duplicate when patching.

Your best bet would be to experiment (on a separate practice surface) with various combinations of soupy plaster or texture paint using thick nap rollers, stippling rollers, stucco floats, etc. **Or** hire a reputable plasterer or decorator to redo the whole wall when your repairs are complete. Yours is a common problem with no easy solution.